# Widower: sexist nonusage?

Tags: social-gender

Collins Cobuild Usage 2004 reads

> Unlike *widow*, when a woman has died you do not refer to her husband as
> '*her **widower**'*.

Which seems supported by [Ngram data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his%20widow%2C%20her%20widower&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chis%20widow%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhis%20widow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHis%20widow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhis%20Widow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cher%20widower%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bher%20widower%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHer%20widower%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Chis%20widow%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhis%20widow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHis%20widow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhis%20Widow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cher%20widower%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bher%20widower%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHer%20widower%3B%2Cc0)

[How should I express such notion instead then](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/widower-usage.3860802/post-19738396)?

Comment: That's an interesting find. Logically it should work both ways, but it does sound a little strange to say (in a fuller sentence) "After Mary died, her widower moved to a smaller place." But I don't think it is a prescription... it sounds more like that it is a much rarer situation (husbands tend to die before the wives). Do you have a link to this 'Collins Cobuild Usage'? You may also want to look up what other style guides might say.

Comment: The sexist part is that widows outnumber widowers by far :-)

Comment: This was mentioned by Robin Lakoff in her 1973 book _Language and Women's Place_.

Comment: @Mitch - it sounds even weirder in a world where same-sex marriage exists: "After John died, his widower moved to a smaller place."

Comment: @CanadianYankee That's only because same-sex marriage is so new. We are getting used to "his husband" and "her wife" but so few (comparatively) same sex spouses have died that the terms "her widow" and "his widower" have not, thankfully, had to be used much yet

Comment: No, the sexist part is that formerly women were almost always treated in law and custom as the property of a man: her father, husband, or somtimes another relative such as a brother or uncle. When a husband died, his wife remained "his" until such time as she married again and becamse another man's property. But once a wife died her husband became a free agent, no longer needing to be identified by refernce to her, so not "her widower".

Answer (score 3):

The phrase has seen usage in a wide range of publications, so the advice seems unwarranted.

> Marianna's early death left Maria Teresa with a sentimental devotion
> to **her widower**. (Marie Antoinette :the journey; Fraser, Antonia;
> New York : N.A. Talese/Doubleday 2001)
>
> Now, **her widower** and her mother are engaged in a very regrettable,
> seemingly intractable battle over who has the right to tell her life
> story. (Jezebel; Mother and Widower of Assisted Suicide Advocate
> Brittany Maynard ...: 2016)
>
> Many historians have thought that **her widower's** promptness in
> putting himself back into matrimonial circulation, very soon after
> Elizabeth 118 Henry VII died, showed he cared nothing about her. (The
> Kings and Queens of England; Jane Murray; Charles Scribner's Sons, New
> York, 1974)
>
> It was not much more than six months after Mary Godwin's death when we
> find **her widower** in pursuit of Miss Harriet Lee, one of the
> authors of the " Canterbury Tales, " a collection which had its day
> when our grandmothers ransacked the circulating libraries, but which
> is probably now only remembered because one of them suggested the plot
> of the tragedy of Werner to Lord Byron. (Paul's William Godwin; North
> American Review: July 1876: 221-233)
>
> The concern of the people of Glasgow has been occasioned by the fact
> that the procurator fiscal has chosen at this stage not to prefer
> charges or identify someone as responsible for the death of Helen
> Tinney: Her family--; specifically **her widower**, Mr: Eddie Tinney,
> her daughters Maureen and Elaine Tinney, and her son John--; and many
> other people are very concerned about this matter (House of Commons
> British Parliament; Mr Mike Watson; 1994)
>
> Although I think we should not spend too much time on this, the
> Government have indicated what it will cost: Clause 2 gives the annual
> payment under Clause 1, which will be £ 1,000 to a former Member, £
> 500 to his widow or **her widower** (House of Lords British
> Parliament; Mr Thomas Peart; 1981)
>
> Two suspects were named in Jensen's murder. **Her widower** Christian
> seemed glad of this, but noted that in Germany, normally, " when two
> cars bump, you have to get out. " (Time Magazine; Fighting Fear in
> Florida; 1993)
>
> ...under 42 U.S.C. 402 (f) (1) (D) such benefits on the basis of the
> earnings of a deceased wife covered by the Act are payable to **her
> widower** only if he was receiving at least half of his support from
> her. (US Supreme Court 430 U.S. 199; CALIFANO v. GOLDFARB; 1977)
>
> Where an author is dead, his or her termination interest is owned, and
> may be exercised, by his widow or **her widower** and his or her children
> or grandchildren (US Supreme Court 469 U.S. 153; MILLS MUSIC, INC. v.
> SNYDER; 1985)
>
> Thirty-seven years after actress Natalie Wood mysteriously drowned,
> Los Angeles Sheriff investigators are calling **her widower** a "
> person of interest " in the case, according to a new report. (Fortune;
> Report: Robert Wagner Named 'Person of Interest' in Natalie Wood's
> ...; 2018)
>
> Mrs. Levin's death will be recorded as natural. Which means **her
> widower** has no claim against McCafferty or the hospital and no way
> to know what really happened to his wife. (TV SERIES Crossing Jordan;
> The Gift of Life; 2002)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to him as "her surviving husband" or "her surviving spouse".

Comment: Or just "her husband" if the context allows.

Answer (score 1):

If people are sexist, then their language will be too. Nevertheless, the word "**widower**" exists, so go ahead and use it. And nobody can stop you from prefixing it with "**her**" (that's just silly).

---

**Widower** - A husband who has lost his wife by death and has not married again.

*William was a **widower**, but…he married again.*

Source: SOED

Comment: The question wasn't about the use of the word _widower_ but specifically about the rarity of the phrase _her widower_.

Comment: @ColinFine Not according to the title and bold font.

Comment: @ColinFine I plainly addressed that phrase. I said it was silly to suppose we couldn't use it. Would you like me to explain why the word **her** can go in front of the word **widower**?

Comment: OK, I see that there is some ambiguity in the question. I (and at least some of the people who commented on the question) took it as being about the phrase _her widower_, not about the word _widower_.